# jQuery $.delegate() single selector multiple events or is $.bind() a better solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

So I am trying to find the answer to this, but there seems to be no definitive one I can find to help me make the right choice.

So What I am curious about is `$.delegate()` as of recently I am a fan of using it, seems to be a bit more stable in most of my apps now a days. So with that. I typically when using it will do something like

```
$('div').delegate('.someclass', 'click', function(e){ .... });
```

and I am good with that, until now. Where I have an element that I need to handle multiple events for. So I am wondering whats the best approach? do I do something to the extent of.

```
$('div').delegate('.someclass', 'click', function(e){ .... });
$('div').delegate('.someclass', 'mouseover', function(e){ .... });
$('div').delegate('.someclass', 'mouseout', function(e){ .... });
```

or do I go the `$.bind()` route? and do something like

```
$('.someclass').bind({
    click:function(){...},
    mouseout:function(){...},
    mouseover:function(){...}
});
```

does `$.delegate()` support something similar to `$.bind()`? It doesn't appear so reading through the API but ya never know (doesn't work for me). Or is there a function I simliar in nature to the combination of the two that I might not be aware of?

Comment: I always use .on() (http://api.jquery.com/on/) when I can, works perfectly all the time

Comment: Your two choices are not functionally equivalent.  One provides event delegation and the other does not.  It really comes down to whether or not you need delegation.  Either way I would agree that you should use `on` in either situation.

Comment: Well for some time I used live, and I started to see a lot of problems with memory leaks, and then stumbled across delegate as an alternative. I try to avoid bind generally speaking cause sometimes I end up with undesired results. Overall I have elements being created post render, and multiple of those elements of which have different event triggers for each, and I'd ultimately like to write less and get more for my buck if you know what I mean. So I am seeking that alternative in attempts of grabbing on to something better suited, which after reading the feedback here and the API `on` is good

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.delegate` and `.bind` have been superseeded by `on.()` as of **jQuery ver 1.7**

```
$('div').on({
    click:function(){...},
    mouseout:function(){...},
    mouseover:function(){...}
},'.someclass');
```

---

```
$('div').on( 'click mouseover mouseout','.someclass', function(e){ .... });
```

This approach can be used when you want to delegate the event..

Comment: neither of them have been depreciated, FYI. they just aren't preferred.

Comment: Using the first approach, you can still delegate by passing a selector as the second parameter. (sorry for the nitpicking!)

Comment: @bfavaretto.. Not a problem  ;) ... Always good to learn from others.. )

Comment: I was unaware of `on()`, I think I may start to switch towards that then. Curious, is `on()` capable of multiple selectors as well or is one to one, with multiple events allowed?

Comment: You can assign multiple selectors using .on()  $('.a ,.b , .c').on(''

Comment: BTW `.delegate()` also supports multiple events separated by spaces. Like `.delegate(".someclass", "click mouseover mouseout", function()...)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. I have correct result view.

```
$('div').delegate('.someclass', 'click mouseover mouseout', function(e){ .... });
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that all of those events are different then each other? if so then you could use the event map on the method [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) if you update to at least jquery 1.7:

```
$('div').on({
    'click': function(e){ .... },
    'mouseover': function(e){ .... },
    'mouseout': function(e){ .... }
}, '.someclass');
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be best if you just started using the new event management functions: on() and off(). They enable you to use both delegated and standard events using the condensed syntax, e.g.:

```
$("a").on({
    click: function() {},
    mouseover: {}
});  // ordinary event handlers

$("div").on({
    click: function() {},
    keydown: function() {}
}, "a.cls");  // delegated
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods that you suggested are deprecated as of jQuery ver 1.7.
use the .on() method instead as it provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers.
To remove events bound with .on(), use [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/). 
Or if you want event that called only once use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the reason why delegate is more stable for you then bind is because delegate has the same result as live(). This means that delegate() also binds events to dynamically generated elements.

As for the recommendations for using on(), I always liked the distinction between live() and bind() because it told me something about the nature of the eventbinding.

I don't know how jQuery is optimizing the on() function. Live() was always a bit heavier then bind().

Answer (score -1):

it's important to note that delegate and live have different functionality from bind and on though. delegate and live both would bind events to any current and future elements. The on method only attached itself to the element being selected at the time.

chris was seeing better results on his page because he is probably not binding and unbinding events properly as the users of his page use it.

He should look into that separately and switch to .on() overall.

chris... may I suggest looking into backbonejs or some other MVC system that will do this sort of thing for you and clean up most of the mess when it's done.

http://backbonejs.org/

Comment: on works as a delegate also: `.on( events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject) )` and the docs also staye: "As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method."

Comment: This isn't completely accurate.  `on` can act the same as `bind`, `delegate` or `live` depending on the parameters passed.